# First Application Install time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I have been trying to get the first install time of a certain package in the android system! ( third party application ) I used package info to get details and from that, FirstInstallTime() method to get the date and time. but it returns a log value that I have no idea converting! can any one help me to convert this value to a date time value!

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classic never gets old :)

```
private String getDateTime() {
    // get date time in custom format
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("[yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss]");
    return sdf.format(new Date(appInfo.firstInstallTime));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[PackageInfo.firstInstallTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#firstInstallTime) gives you the install time in *"Unix time"* (the time in milliseconds since *"the epoch"*, i.e. *January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC*). You may use [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) or [java.text.DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) in order to format this time.

```
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

...
packageName = ...
...

try {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

    Date installTime = new Date( packageInfo.firstInstallTime );
    Log.d(TAG, "Installed: " + installTime.toString());

    Date updateTime = new Date( packageInfo.lastUpdateTime );
    Log.d(TAG, "Updated: " + updateTime.toString());
}
catch ( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can also change the date format with [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

String installTime = dateFormat.format( new Date( packageInfo.firstInstallTime ) );
Log.d(TAG, "Installed: " + installTime);

String updateTime = dateFormat.format( new Date( packageInfo.lastUpdateTime ) );
Log.d(TAG, "Updated: " + updateTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's just a date stored as a long, there is no magic just create a date from it.

```
Date firstInstallTime = new Date(pInfo.firstInstallTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the **Time in long type**.... then try the following...

```
public class Chk {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time in long: "+l);

    System.out.println(new Date(l));

    }

}
```